# Zip a file using FTP/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have access to a wordpress theme folder directory via FTP. I want a particular  folder to be ziped inside the theme folder so i can download it. What code i use?

```
/wp-content/themes/  - my directory to access
```

My theme folder name is 'vintage'

I want upload and run a php code inside /wp-content/themes/ so it makde a zip file or the folder 'vintage' located at /wp-content/themes/ can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like:

```
system('cd /path/to/htdocs/wp-content/themes/; zip -r vintage.zip ./');
```